# Comparing different strings in consecutive cells highlighting on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm designing a shift roster and want to ensure person working in C shift (night shift) is not assigned shift A (morning shift) because it becomes a continous shift.

This means, if value of cell `A12=C` and `B12=A` then `B12` should be highligted as RED.

Take example below:

```
Col A Col B 
C A  B C B B B B A B C A
```

It should throw me an error on the first and last cell of column B.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, your example isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select column B then in "Home" tab select "Conditional Formatting" > New Rule > "use a formula to determine which cell to format" > in the box below type this formula

`=AND(A1="C",B1="A")`

and then click "Format" button to set required format (red fill)

That will then highlight any "A" entry in column B where column A in same row = "C"

Instructions apply to Excel 2007 or later